# Trigger doesn't let me update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following Trigger:

```
  delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER DES1actualizarConsultaR_update
AFTER UPDATE ON ranking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE player P,
    (SELECT 
        J.player_id AS jugador_id,
            SUM(ranking_points) AS PuntosTotales
    FROM
        player J
    INNER JOIN ranking R ON R.player_id = NEW.player_id
    GROUP BY J.player_id) AS TD 
SET 
    P.totalPuntos = TD.PuntosTotales
WHERE
    P.player_id = TD.jugador_id;

UPDATE player P,
    (SELECT 
        J.player_id AS JnumUno, COUNT(*) AS NumVeces1
    FROM
        player J
    INNER JOIN ranking R ON R.player_id = NEW.player_id
    WHERE
        R.ranking = '1'
    GROUP BY J.player_id) AS TD 
SET 
    P.vecesNum1 = TD.NumVeces1
WHERE
    P.player_id = TD.JnumUno;

END |
```

I'am trying to execute this update:

```
UPDATE ranking 
SET 
    ranking_points = (ranking_points + 10)
WHERE
    player_id IN (SELECT 
            P.player_id
        FROM
            player P,
            tourney T,
            tmatch M
        WHERE
            T.tourney_name LIKE 'Madrid%'
                AND T.tourney_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
                AND (M.round = 'F' OR M.round = 'SF')
                AND P.player_id = M.winner_id
                AND M.tourney_id = T.tourney_id);
```

But I have this error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'player' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

How can I do the update query?

I´m using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are have a jointure on the `ranking` table in the TRIGGER's UPDATE statement.

Even if you aren't updating the `ranking` table itself, MySQL doesn't like it.

You have to get around it by doing a stand-alone SELECT query first to compute the player's points, save those points in a variable, and then use it in your UPDATE of the `player` table, without referencing the `ranking` table

Here's the idea:

```
 delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER DES1actualizarConsultaR_update
AFTER UPDATE ON ranking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE vPuntosTotales INT;
    DECLARE vNumVeces1 INT;

    SELECT SUM(ranking_points) AS PuntosTotales INTO vPuntosTotales 
    FROM ranking  
    WHERE player_id = NEW.player_id;


    UPDATE player SET totalPuntos = vPuntosTotales WHERE player_id = NEW.player_id;


    -- NOT SURE IF THIS ONE IS CORRECT
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumVeces1 INTO vNumVeces1 
    FROM ranking R 
    WHERE R.ranking = '1' AND R.player_id = NEW.player_id;  


    UPDATE player SET vecesNum1 = vNumVeces1 WHERE player_id = NEW.player_id;

END |
```

you should review my queries because I don't know exactly your table structure and I might be wrong in my SELECTs, especially in the second one

Comment: I know what you mean, I will try it. If I have any problem I will tell you. Thanks.